# SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application threw load() exception

Tags: java, spring

i am NEW to spring i am trying to exccute this application i got the exception like this

```
SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [/loginDB] threw load()    exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.Aware
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2503)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:831)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2503)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:831)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2503)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:831)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 23, 2016 10:01:18 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable            debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve       startup time and JSP compilation time.
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:18 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:18 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
 INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Sat Jul 23 22:01:18 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
 INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:19 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
 INFO: Mapped URL path [/test] onto handler 'welcomeController'
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:19 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
 INFO: Mapped URL path [/test.*] onto handler 'welcomeController'
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:19 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
 INFO: Mapped URL path [/test/] onto handler 'welcomeController'
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:19 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
 INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 1283 ms
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
 INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2016"]
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
 INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 6529 ms
 Jul 23, 2016 10:01:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
WARNING: Servlet spring is currently unavailable
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
<!-- enable component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="pack1"/>
<!-- handlermapping -->
<bean id="handlermapping"            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotation
HandlerMapping"/>
 <!-- view resolverconfiguration -->
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
 <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
 <property name="database" ref="ds"/> 
</bean>
<bean id="ds"   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl1"/>
<property name="username" value="scott"/>
 <property name="password" value="sada"/>
</bean>
```

LoginController.java

```
package pack1.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import pack1.dao.LoginDao;

 @Controller
public class LoginController {
@Autowired
private LoginDao dao;
@RequestMapping(value="/logins",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getLoginPage()
{
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
@RequestMapping(value="/check",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView checkLogin(@RequestParam("t1") String  s1,@RequestParam("t2")String s2)
{
    boolean b=dao.check(s1, s2);
    if(b)
    {
        return new ModelAndView("success");
    }
    else
    {
        return new ModelAndView("failure");
    }
}
}
```

loginDao.java(i)

```
package pack1.dao;

public interface LoginDao {
boolean check(String s1,String s2);
}
```

loginDaoImpl.java(c)

```
 package pack1.dao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository 
public class LoginDaoImpl implements LoginDao {
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jt;
public boolean check(String s1, String s2) {
    int i=(Integer)jt.queryForObject("select count(*) from login where username=? and password=?",Integer.class,s1,s2);
    if(i==1)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
 }
 }
```

index.jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="logins.form"></jsp:forward>
```

pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.sada</groupId>
 <artifactId>loginDB</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <name>loginDB</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc   -->
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

 <build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
       <target>1.5</target>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and some other jsp pages .any one can help me resolve the probleam

Comment: please post your pom.xml.

Comment: now i add pom.xml you can check

Answer (score 1):

Check your Spring version. May be outdated. Update that to latest version and then run the program.

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691468/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-beans-factory-aware)

Comment: thanks @SivaKumar i tried that way but i did not get the result ,same error occured again

Comment: Just do a maven clean and rebuild the whole project and see

Answer (score 1):

In your pom you have 3.0.6.RELEASE dependencies . Its too old

upgrade your spring jdbc like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: hey thanks@Georges van houtte for reply but that mistack was i done in here only now i am edited

Comment: dont forget to update your maven repo with : Project -> Maven -> Update Configuration

Comment: thanks, i am working on it now some probleam with eclipse .if anything wrong i will ask

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="edao" class="pack1.dao.loginDao">  
<property name="template" ref="jt"></property>  
</bean>
```

Add in your spring-servlet.xml.